# Creating an xts object results in altered timestamps

Tags: r, time-series, xts

Suppose I have:

```
R> str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ datetime: Factor w/ 4 levels "2011-01-05 09:30:00.001",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ price   : num  18.3 18.3 18.3 18.3

R> data
                 datetime price
1 2011-01-05 09:30:00.001 18.31
2 2011-01-05 09:30:00.321 18.33
3 2011-01-05 09:30:01.511 18.33
4 2011-01-05 09:30:02.192 18.34
```

When I try to load this into an `xts` object the timestamps are subtly altered:

```
R> x <- xts(data[-1], as.POSIXct(strptime(data$datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
R> str(x)
An ‘xts’ object from 2011-01-05 09:30:00.000 to 2011-01-05 09:30:02.191 containing:
  Data: num [1:4, 1] 18.3 18.3 18.3 18.3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "price"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

 R> x
                         price
 2011-01-05 09:30:00.000 18.31
 2011-01-05 09:30:00.321 18.33
 2011-01-05 09:30:01.510 18.33
 2011-01-05 09:30:02.191 18.34
```

You'll notice that the timestamps have been altered. The first entry now occurs at `09:30:00.000` instead of what the original data said, `09:30:00.001`. The third and fourth rows are also incorrect.

What's causing this? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I've tried various incantations to get the data into an `xts` object and they all seem to exhibit this behavior.

**EDIT:** Add `sessionInfo()`

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C               LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.8-2 zoo_1.7-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.13.1     lattice_0.19-30 tools_2.13.1
```

**EDIT 2:** If I modify my source data to be microsecond precision as follows:

```
datetime,price
2011-01-05 09:30:00.001000,18.31
2011-01-05 09:30:00.321000,18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:01.511000,18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:02.192000,18.34
```

And then load it so I have:

```
R> test
                    datetime price
1 2011-01-05 09:30:00.001000 18.31
2 2011-01-05 09:30:00.321000 18.33
3 2011-01-05 09:30:01.511000 18.33
4 2011-01-05 09:30:02.192000 18.34
```

And then, finally, convert it into an `xts` object and set the index format:

```
R> x <- xts(test[,-1], as.POSIXct(strptime(test$datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
R> indexFormat(x) <- '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6'
R> x
                            [,1]
2011-01-05 09:30:00.000999 18.31
2011-01-05 09:30:00.321000 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:01.510999 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:02.191999 18.34
```

You can see the effect as well. I was hoping that adding the extra precision would help, but unfortunately it does not.

**EDIT 3:** Please see [@DWin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341857/creating-an-xts-object-results-in-altered-timestamps/7343009#7343009) for an end-to-end test case that reproduces this behavior.

**EDIT 4:** The behavior does not appear to be millisecond oriented. The following shows the same altered result of a microsecond resolution timestamp. If I change my input data to:

```
R> data
                    datetime price
1 2011-01-05 09:30:00.001001 18.31
2 2011-01-05 09:30:00.321001 18.33
3 2011-01-05 09:30:01.511001 18.33
4 2011-01-05 09:30:02.192005 18.34
```

And then create an `xts` object:

```
R> x <- xts(data[-1], 
            as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(data$datetime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
R> indexFormat(x) <- '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6'
R> x
                           price
2011-01-05 09:30:00.001000 18.31
2011-01-05 09:30:00.321001 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:01.511001 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:02.192004 18.34
```

**EDIT 5:** It would appear to be a floating point precision issue. Observe:

```
R> t <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-05 09:30:00.001001")
R> t
[1] "2011-01-05 09:30:00.001 CST"
R> as.numeric(t)
[1] 1294241400.0010008812
```

This exhibits the error behavior, and is consistent with the example in EDIT 4. However, using an example that didn't show the error:

```
R> t <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-05 09:30:01.511001")
R> t
[1] "2011-01-05 09:30:01.511001 CST"
R> as.numeric(t)
[1] 1294241401.5110011101
```

It seems as if `xts` or some underlying component is rounding down rather than to the nearest?

Comment: I can't replicate this... what's your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: added `sessionInfo()` output as an edit

Comment: I have a memory that zoo objects, to which xts is a related, get their index values slightly expanded at the beginnings and ends of the series. Or is that just with seq.zoo? That doesn't actually explain all that you are seeing since the upper end it getting "pushed back, too. Could this be a leap second issue?

Comment: There is no such method as `seq.zoo`.  Its not clear what "slightly expanded" refers to but the implication that zoo does some sort of untoward mucking around with index values without asking is unlikely.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am perhaps conflating the behavior of some other function, `hist` or `cut` perhaps, that has a method that expands a datetime range to avoid dropping off events at the extremes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is only in printing.  Using the OP's original `data`:

```
ind <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data$datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS'))
as.numeric(ind)*1e6  # as expected
# [1] 1294241400001000 1294241400321000 1294241401511000 1294241402192000
ind  # wrong
# [1] "2011-01-05 09:30:00.000 CST" "2011-01-05 09:30:00.321 CST"
# [3] "2011-01-05 09:30:01.510 CST" "2011-01-05 09:30:02.191 CST"
x <- xts(data[-1], ind)
x  # wrong
#                         price
# 2011-01-05 09:30:00.000 18.31
# 2011-01-05 09:30:00.321 18.33
# 2011-01-05 09:30:01.510 18.33
# 2011-01-05 09:30:02.191 18.34
as.numeric(index(x))*1e6  # but the underlying index values are as expected
# [1] 1294241400001000 1294241400321000 1294241401511000 1294241402192000
```

Comment: Would it be considered a bug in `xts` that it doesn't print the exact correct timestamp?

Comment: This isn't an xts bug.  xts is just formatting / printing `POSIXct` objects.  You can see in my answer that the xts index is formatted exactly like `ind`.  The question is why `format.POSIXct` does that.

Answer (score 3):

You have your times in a factor:

```
R> str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ datetime: Factor w/ 4 levels "2011-01-05 09:30:00.001",..: 1 2 3 4
 [...]
```

That is not the best place to start.  You need to convert to character. Hence instead of

```
x <- xts(data[-1], as.POSIXct(strptime(data$datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
```

I would suggest

```
x <- xts(data[-1], 
         order.by=as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(data$datetime), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
```

In my experience, the `as.character()` around a factor is critical.  Factors are powerful for modeling, they are however a bit of a nuisance when you get them accidentally from reading data. Use `stringsAsFactor=FALSE` to your advantage and avoid them on data import.

**Edit:**  So this appears to point to the strptime/strftime implementations.  To make matters more interesting, R takes some of these from the operating system and reimplements some in `src/main/datetime.c`.

Also, pay attention to the smallest *epsilon* you can add to a time variable and still have  R see them as equal.  On my 64-bit Linux system, this happens 10^-7 :

```
R> sapply(seq(1, 8), FUN=function(x) identical(now, now+1/10^x)) 
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Dirk, unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any affect. I tried wrapping the timestamp with `as.character()` and I tried reading the data and specifying `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Neither changed the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Dirk. I see the same as you re: epsilon.

Answer (score 2):

I post this just so people who want to explore it can have a reproducible example which shows that it happens on more than just the OP's system. `as.character` to the factor does not keep it from occurring.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("     datetime\tprice
 1\t2011-01-05 09:30:00.001\t18.31
 2\t2011-01-05 09:30:00.321\t18.33
 3\t2011-01-05 09:30:01.511\t18.33
 4\t2011-01-05 09:30:02.192\t18.34"), header =TRUE, sep="\t")
 as.character(dat$datetime)
#[1] "2011-01-05 09:30:00.001" "2011-01-05 09:30:00.321" "2011-01-05 09:30:01.511"
#[4] "2011-01-05 09:30:02.192"
  strptime(as.character(dat$datetime),         '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')
#[1] "2011-01-05 09:30:00" "2011-01-05 09:30:00" "2011-01-05 09:30:01"
#[4] "2011-01-05 09:30:02"
 as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(dat$datetime), 
                                       '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS'))
#[1] "2011-01-05 09:30:00 EST" "2011-01-05 09:30:00 EST" "2011-01-05 09:30:01 EST"
#[4] "2011-01-05 09:30:02 EST"
 x <- xts(dat[-1], 
          order.by=as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(dat$datetime), 
                                       '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')))
 x
####                price
2011-01-05 09:30:00 18.31
2011-01-05 09:30:00 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:01 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:02 18.34
indexFormat(x) <- '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6'
x
                           price
2011-01-05 09:30:00.000999 18.31
2011-01-05 09:30:00.321000 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:01.510999 18.33
2011-01-05 09:30:02.191999 18.34

sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 RC (2011-07-03 r56263)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xts_0.8-2       zoo_1.7-4       sculpt3d_0.2-2  RGtk2_2.20.12  
 [5] rgl_0.92.798    survey_3.24     hexbin_1.26.0   spam_0.23-0    
 [9] xtable_1.5-6    polspline_1.1.5 Ryacas_0.2-10   XML_3.4-0      
[13] rms_3.3-1       Hmisc_3.8-3     survival_2.36-9 sos_1.3-0      
[17] brew_1.0-6      lattice_0.19-30

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.14.0 tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an end-to-end example that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: This still works as expected for me on Ubuntu 64-bit with xts/zoo from CRAN... odd.

Comment: @Joshua, please see my most recent edit. It appears to be a floating point precision issue with rounding. Does that spark any ideas as to how this might be avoided? The rounding seems off, as it appears to always round down rather than to the nearest.